# making multiple async call without being dependent on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js

in a **Node.JS** app, I am trying to make 3 API calls to different endpoints, which are:

`/GET ProductInformation` : returns the information for the given `productID`.

`/GET ProductRecommendation` : returns the product recommendation for the given `productID`

`/GET ProductReview` : returns product reviews and rating for the given `productID`

None of the above call is dependent on the other, therefore, **if possible, I am trying to avoid** a chain of `Promise` like :

```
getProductInfo(productId)
.then(result =>{
      getProductRecommendation(productId)
.then(result =>{
      getProductReview(result => {
      callback('done') // all calls are done, we can return now!
     })
})
```

Is there a better approach for making this sort of `async` operations ? 
The reason that I am looking to see if there is a better way or not, is because in reality I have more than just 3 calls, and doing this makes the code hard to maintain and read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.all` will run these all in parallel. If any of the promises fail it will go to `.catch()`.

```
Promise.all([
  getProductInfo(productId),
  getProductRecommendation(productId),
  getProductReview()
])
.then(function(results){callback('done')})
.catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Comment: would it be possible to still return in case of partial failure? example, 1 out of the 10 services failed to respond.

Comment: Possibly, I need to test it real quick before I post something

Comment: You can do something like `getProductInfo(productId).catch(err=>console.log(err))` and it will continue on to .then(), but doing something like "1/10" is more complicated.  If you need more fine grain control I would look into async/await and try{}catch(e){} on each api call. --- or a promise library that will help orchestrate some of this.  https://repl.it/@CodyGeisler/MediumbluePeachpuffRegression?lite=&classroom_template=&outputonly=&fileName=

Comment: [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) will give you an array that tells you the results.